# Scenes vs Stages in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stage, scene

I have a program I'm putting together in FlashDevelop that will have several different windows, with buttons on the side of each window that allow the user to go from one window to the next.  The windows will not be open at the same time- essentially the background just needs to be redrawn and features added or deleted.  The buttons on the side of the windows will be the same.

Right now things work just fine, except that the bitmaps are being drawn from the top left corner of the button as opposed to the top left corner of the window.  I asked this question a month ago and got an answer related to scenes.  I've been busy and haven't had much time to work with this, but that does not seem to work.  If I understand correctly, scenes are just different portions of the timeline.  I am not using Flash, otherwise this would be simple- goToAndPlay.

What am I missing here?  Should I be using the Stage or Document class?  Code is below, at this point I'm just drawing a black rectangle but things work the same when I do bitmaps:

From Main:

```
songbutton = new SongButton;
addChild(songbutton);
songbutton.x = 680;
songbutton.y = 100;
```

From SongButton:

```
public class SongButton extends MusicPlay
{   
        public var songsYellow:Loader;
        public var songsWhite:Loader;
        public function SongButton(): void
        {
            songsYellow = new Loader();
            songsYellow.load(new URLRequest("images/SongsYellow.jpg"));
            songsWhite = new Loader();
            songsWhite.load(new URLRequest("images/SongsWhite.jpg"));
            addChild(songsWhite);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOver);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOut);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
        }

        private function mouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
            addChild(songsYellow);
        }
        private function mouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
            addChild(songsWhite);
        }
        private function mouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
            SetMusicScreen();
        }
}
```

From MusicPlay:

```
public function SetMusicScreen():void 
{
    graphics.beginFill(0x0);
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 800, 550);
    graphics.endFill();
}
```

Comment: There are a billion ways to make buttons and put them on screen, so... can you post the code you're using to do this?
In general, everything aligns to the top-left of its parent container. So it's going to depend what you're adding the buttons to -- whether that's the stage or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a way to do this.  Might not be the best way, but it turns out that I can put an addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, gottaMouseUp) in the calling class, add a public variable in the button class that lets me know if the correct button has been clicked, and use that in the calling class to decide which button was clicked.  I knew it was something simple like that....

Answer (score 0):

In Flash at least, you can have Flash draw directly on the stage via `stage.graphics.beginFill(0x0);`

If, for whatever reason, that's outside of scope, you should also be able to get to the parent of the MovieClip via `MovieClip(parent).graphics.beginfill(0x0);` To get to further parents beyond that, you can "step back" with `MovieClip(parent.parent)`, `MovieClip(parent.parent.parent)`, and so on.

Whether this applies to FlashDevelop, I don't know. I'd think it would, since it is based in ActionScript 3.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work with FlashDevelop- that's basically Flash stuff.  Clearly I'm missing something fairly obvious, there has to be a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> except that the bitmaps are being drawn from the top left corner of the button

Because you are using Graphics object of the button

```
public function SetMusicScreen():void 
{
    graphics.beginFill(0x0);
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 800, 550);
    graphics.endFill();
}
```

`SetMusicScreen` is method of your button, and `graphics` is also related to the button. You should change logic of `SetMusicScreen` method, It should reference correct Graphics object. For example, such method will change background color of your application:

```
function SetMusicScreen():void {
    //This will change background color of document class
    var myRoot: Sprite = Sprite(root);

    myRoot.graphics.clear();
    myRoot.graphics.beginFill(0);
    myRoot.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight); //x,y, width, height
}
```

You could place window sprite object, that will change colors, or you can in `SetMusicScreen`, offset drawing along X axis, so background under buttons on the left site don't change.

Comment: I get an error when I do that on var myRoot: Sprite = Sprite(root);.  "Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 0."

Comment: Is your document class Sprite? If you use MovieClip as Document class → `var myRoot: MovieClip = MovieClip(root);`

Comment: I get the same error...  You are absolutely correct that the current code is accessing the wrong graphics object.